# Find All based on the flag value in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to fetch all the records based on the flag value. Flag value can be either 'A' for Active or 'I' for Inactive.
I want to fetch both Active and Inactive records and put them in some kind of List or Map.
These are my repository and entity class:

```
@Repository
public interface StatusRepository extends JpaRepository<StatusEntity,Long>{

}

public class StatusEntity{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_status")
    private Long idStatus;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="status_flg")
    private String statusFlg;

}
```

I am able to fetch all the records using `statusRepository.findAll()`. I was wondering if there is something like `statusRepository.findAllByStatusFlg(String flag)` or `statusRepository.findByStatusFlg(String flag)`?
Is there any way to fetch all the records by specifying where condition on certain columns?

P.S. I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.3.2.RELEASE`

Answer (score 0):

You should make yourself familiar with the basics of [spring data](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/). As you thought, you can define a [query method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods) in your `StatusRepository` that fetches your `StatusEntity`s according to your needs.

```
@Repository
public interface StatusRepository extends JpaRepository<StatusEntity,Long>{

    List<StatusEntity> findByStatusFlg(String flag);

}
```